# Is it possible to change the text size in the code Markdown content?

Tags: discussion, support, markdown

I recently answered my first question over on [Programmers.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/188128/java-xml-intraction-in-android/188379#188379) (PSE) and noticed that the font for my code snippets was smaller and looked a lot nicer than my snippets on Stack Overflow.  Is it possible to reduce the font size of my code Markdown content here on Stack Overflow to match that of Programmers.SE?

I typically program in a 6-8 pt font, so I can get as much code on the screen as possible and just really liked the way the Markdown content looked on PSE as compared to Stack Overflow.

Just a note, my browser text size is already small, so reducing that overall isn't an option.

Also, I'm not looking to get this changed for everybody across the entire site as I know changing all the Markdown content on the site to match my preferences would be a bit drastic.  I'm looking for a way I can change this through some sort of preferences I might not know about or some other method, so that it appears different for me.

Here's an example of the difference I'm seeing taken straight from two answers I've given.

[image: Example of the difference.]

Comment: Just for the record, as far as I can tell, I see the same font and size on both sites.

Comment: It appears to only be a 2pt difference between the two but, just looking at the both of them side by side, it looks like a big difference.

Comment: I see no such difference even having them directly next to each other. Browser thing?

Comment: I thought that first but I don't alter my browser in any way whatsoever.  I run the latest stable release of Chrome for Linux.

Comment: Just took a look in Konqueror, indeed there the fontsize on [programmers.se] is smaller. I'm not sure it's a different font, but tend to believe so. It's identical in SeaMonkey.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Stack Overflow: `font-family: Arial,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif; font-size: 80%;` - Programmers: `font-family: Tahoma,Geneva,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 12px;` - So depending on which fonts you have installed, you'd get slightly different views.

Comment: I agree with this post: the first code block is a lot easier to grasp at a glance. But to each their own.

Comment: "PSE" is ambiguous. It has also been used for *[Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tour)*.

Comment: *Programmers* was renamed to *[Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour)* in [2016](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8266/its-official-programmers-is-now-software-engineering-stack-exchange).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, there is no way to explicitly change the font-size at all within a post (some people do use headers and the `<sub>` element to achieve the effect though).

The font-size is specific to each site. Each site expects that the font will always be the same size, so changing the font-size on Stack Overflow to match Programmers would throw a lot of people off here because they don't expect it.

Formatting a post is meant to make it easier for *everyone* to read, not for you to make it match other sites - that's what user styles are for.

Comment: I understand changing how the markdown looks for everybody or even changing how my posts appear from other people's posts would be ridiculous.  I was looking for a way to make the markdown look smaller to me through some sort of preferences or other such method.  I have updated my question to reflect this.

Comment: @MCeley: Stack Exchange does not keep any preferences of the such. You're better off installing a plugin, such as Stylish, and writing your own CSS styles to manually override the ones on the site.

Comment: @OP If you are using Chrome, download a CSS injector extension and use that. There is one called Stylize (something like that) that I use, but I'm not at my computer right now.

Comment: I wouldn't touch those extensions with a ten foot pole. They make every page on the web take slightly longer to load. You can see it in the debugger's rendering timeline.

Answer (score 7):

I know a guy who knows a guy who knows a plugin for Chrome, Firefox and Opera. It's called [Stylus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylus/clngdbkpkpeebahjckkjfobafhncgmne?hl=en).

You can set custom website styles and have them be permanently applied. (By *Permanent* I mean, until you uninstall the plugin). But you can add this plugin and simply add `* { font-size: 9pt; }` and make it target stack overflow.

[image: How to reduce the font-size for StackOverflow.com]

It's really easy and takes barely 3 minutes.

> **PS**: I may or may not be half a decade late.